# Windows Internals for Linux

Tags: kernel, documentation, books

I've recently been reading Windows Internals version 6 (from Microsoft Press), and found it thoroughly enjoyable.

I'm now using Kubuntu on my work machine, and as such have some desire to learn a bit about how Linux differs from Windows. I want to know everything that I can, and I want it in a decent format. The Windows book is in a very good format for me, and as such I want something as close to it as possible.

So, although there probably isn't a book released by Canonical called "Ubuntu Internals" or "Linux Internals", I'm looking for something as close to that as possible. Can anyone recommend anything?

Here's a section of the blurb from the Windows Internals, book, which more closely depicts what I'd like to see of Linux:

- Understanding how core system and management mechanisms work - including object manager, synchronisation, Wow64, Hyper-V and the registry.
- Examine the data structures and activities behind processes, threads, and jobs.
- Go inside the Windows security model to see how it manages access, auditing, and authorization.
- Explore the Windows networking stack from top to bottom - including APIs, BranchCache, protocol, and NDIS drivers, and layered services.
- Dig into internals hands-on using the kernel debugger, performance monitor, and other tools.

Comment: Linux distributions use the same kernel, and most of the same software layered on top. There is no one "Distribution XYZ unpacked" I'm aware of, stuff is much more spread around lots of separate pieces.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100797.do) by Greg Kroah-Hartman?  Also worth having a look at [Linux Kernel Newbies : Documents](http://kernelnewbies.org/Documents).

Comment: While I'm interested in the Kernel itself, I'm not sure that this quite covers what I'm looking to know... I'll include a section of the blurb from the section 1 Windows Internals book - maybe that will clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

"Understanding the Linux Kernel" by "Daniel P. Bovet, Marco Cesati" could be what you are looking for.

Comment: While I'm interested in the Kernel itself, I'm not sure that this quite covers what I'm looking to know... I'll include a section of the blurb from the section 1 Windows Internals book - maybe that will clarify things.